# Dired - open files in another Emacs window

Tags: emacs, dired

I want to have two Emacs windows on the screen: one for Dired and one for code.  But when I click on a file in the Dired buffer the file opens in the the same window, in place of the Dired buffer.  Can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Why are you clicking on things with a mouse?  I thought you're using Emacs?

Move point to the line you're interested in and press <kbd>o</kbd> to open it in another window or <kbd>C-o</kbd> to open the file but stay on Dired buffer.

If you must do it with the mouse, use middle-click to do the same thing.

Comment: `C-o` didn't work for me, but I think this was supposed to trigger `dired-display-file`. `o` is `dired-find-file-other-window`.

Answer (score 2):

`S-Return` works for me in spacemacs if anyone is interested.

```
dired-find-file-other-window is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`dired.el'.

It is bound to <S-return>, g O, <normal-state> <S-return>, <normal-state> g O,
<menu-bar> <immediate> <find-file-other-window>.

(dired-find-file-other-window)

For more information check the manuals.

In Dired, visit this file or directory in another window.

[back]
```